# create object before return it or return it directly

Tags: language-agnostic

I usually build my function this way

```
public MyObject getMyObject(){
   MyObject myObject = new MyObject()
   return myObject;
}
```

And wonder if doing it this way is "better" in term of performance or in other term.. How do you do it ?

```
public MyObject getMyObject(){
   return new MyObject()
}
```

The example is in Java but it could be any other languages

Thank you

Comment: Java is to Javascript as ham is to hamster. If this is a [tag:language-agnostic] question then tag it as such.

Comment: You shouldnt worry about it so much. Create a reference if you need to refer to the object at sometime within the method before you return (as in calling methods or setting vars). If your intentions are to return a new object, and you dont need to do anything with it after creating and before returning, then you dont need a reference. Im pretty sure this falls under the category of micro-optomization

Comment: In java ... just directly new the object as needed, no reason for a getMyObject() method.  Or use dependency injection with Spring and use autowired, constructor injection or setter injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference in the generated bytecode. You can see the bytecode with `javap -c MyObject.class`.

the first one does this:

```
0: new
3: dup
4: invokespecial
7: astore_1
8: aload_1
9: areturn
```

The second one does this:

```
0: new
3: dup
4: invokespecial
7: areturn
```

The main reasoning however, should be readability and not micro-optimization. In this case I think readability and micro-optimization happen to coincide.

Answer (score 1):

The first way of doing it create a reference to the object that won't be used anymore after the return.

The second way do not creates that reference, and so you can save a bit of memory (a really tiny).

The best criteria is the readability of the code. To me the second solution is more consice and clearer, but it is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no sense in having a myObject variable declared, as it will never be used. To keep the code readable and short, I prefer the second option.